# How to clear and fill MySQL table with php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

We have the following php file, which is supposed to clear the table and add some data to it.

```
 <?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","fontofyo_anon","george", "fontofyo_hashes");
    if (!$con) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }

    mysql_select_db("fontofyo_hashes");

    echo "select 'mysql truncate table ' | table_name
                  from information_schema.tables" | mysql >p2.sh
    bash p2.sh
    //$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hashes")
    //or die(mysql_error());


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hashes
    (hash, name) VALUES('37CDC66676EB82014087EE881D3ABF3EA6973C5E', 'League of Legends Patch 4.17') ") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hashes
    (hash, name) VALUES('EC41E5CB44AFD8BBC5707CD765351AA9AF642D24', 'League of Legends Patch 4.16') ") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hashes
    (hash, name) VALUES('DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709', 'League of Legends Patch 4.15') ") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hashes
    (hash, name) VALUES('D303F6049FBF1CAA552DF51075FAEE1C7DACDD4B', 'League of Legends Patch 4.14') ") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hashes 
    (hash, name) VALUES('7AB515D12BD2CF431745511AC4EE13FED15AB578', 'Legal Document Editor') ") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

However, I am new to PHP and server-side programming and cannot figure out how to actually run this script.  Right now, I have a script in the main html file which includes the following:

```
window.onload=function() {
$.get('DBInit.php');
//more code
}
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?  I've read that you aren't supposed/able to call php scripts from javascript but I can't think of another way to run the php.  I have full privileges, but can ONLY interact with the database with php, which means this program is necessary(I can't just use phpMyAdmin to edit the database).

Comment: mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE `tablename`'); instead of this echo statement

Answer (score 0):

Generaly you'd run PHP via web server - if you put it in public folder inside www folder (let's say "test") of the web-server you can run it like - `http://localhost/test/DBInit.php`.

But you can also run it directly via php command in the terminal:

```
php -f DBInit.php
```

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

You can also run it via wget for example or via cron job ...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE tablename');` insetad of `echo "select 'mysql truncate table ' | table_name
                  from information_schema.tables" | mysql >p2.sh`

Truncate command is used to delete complete data from an existing table.